# What if a method generates a checked exception and handle it itself?

Tags: java, exception

```
class Xyz {
    public static void yolo() {
        try {
            throw new IllegalAccessException("demo");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("lol");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Xyz.yolo();
    }
}
```

Since there is no exception that is going out of the yolo method, I don't need to write "yolo() throws IllegalAccessException". Right?

Comment: If only there were a way to *test* this sort of thing...

Comment: @AntP I see what you did there...

Comment: In an effort to remove @AntP' s tongue from his or her cheek, Don't do this. If you can throw and catch in the same method, it's not an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. You only need to declare unhandled checked exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. A method only needs to declare `throws` for exceptions which leave it and aren't handled by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect!

If you will use `throws` keyword for handing Exception then this method will not handle the exception rather then `main()` will handle this exception at time of calling this method.